# How to select data from a timedelta list

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a list like this. I'm wondering how I can pick out the entries that have less than 21 days of timedelta and I want to keep the index as machine_id.

```
machine_id
13512886     0 days 00:00:00
49645796     0 days 00:00:00
58622574     0 days 00:00:00
59850911   147 days 01:57:40
61433282     0 days 00:00:00
61538672   135 days 23:25:24
61755561   259 days 05:49:49
61876734   259 days 21:00:28
61950006   180 days 04:42:39
62508680    59 days 06:45:46
62549967     0 days 00:00:00
62643307     0 days 00:00:00
62678486     0 days 00:00:00
63761469     0 days 00:00:00
64092088     0 days 00:00:00
64194930     0 days 00:00:00
64543161     0 days 00:00:00
64720467    75 days 01:11:00
65034386     4 days 02:16:30
65118059     0 days 00:00:00
65198554     0 days 00:00:00
65347738     0 days 00:00:00
65524977     0 days 00:00:00
65556861     0 days 00:00:00
                  ...       

95318844     0 days 00:00:00
95318910     0 days 00:00:00
95319088     0 days 00:00:00
95319234   211 days 22:15:05
95319894   163 days 20:18:56
95320067     0 days 00:00:00
Name: event_datetime, Length: 3984, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
series[series < pd.Timedelta(days=21)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a dataframe

`df.loc[df['event_datetime'] < pd.Timedelta(days=21)]`

else @Rohit Raj solution is fine